# How can I apply box Shadow to container similar to that of an elevated button or Materialize CSS on Flutter?

Tags: css, flutter, flutter-layout, material-design, materialize

I have been struggling a lot to achieve this, for all box shadow solutions are just not suitable! Bellow is the result I want to have:
[image]

Comment: Read [Google Material 3: Cards](https://m3.material.io/components/cards/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Just add it like below:

```
                          Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: CachedNetworkImageProvider('your_image'),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                              boxShadow: const [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                              blurRadius: 2.0,
                              spreadRadius: 0.0,
                              offset: Offset(1, 1), //
                            ),
                          ]));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly wrap your container widget in card and use elevation property of card.